# Nonlinear regression: heteroskedasticity and correlated residuals

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, nonlinear-regression, heteroscedasticity

I'm performing regression analysis of some data. I believe I have to use a non-linear model with the form $y = at^b + c$ where $t$ is time. A log transform won't linearize the data here because of the constant term $c$.

When I perform the regression, I get a model that fits the data very well. My R-squared value is 0.996 with an RMSE value 1/100th the scale length of the problem. However, my residuals are growing in time and they exhibit a sinusoidal pattern.

I believe this means they are correlated with non-constant variance. How do I deal with this? All of the theory I've seen developed deals with serial correlation of errors or heteroskedasticity in linear regression only. My best guess is a weighted autoregressive model, but I'm not sure how to pick weights since I've tried the common suggestions and they aren't helping the problem.

Comment: How does time relate to your stated model? Is the $x$ variable time or is time yet another variable?

Comment: @Nick Cox Time is the independent variable. The model should read $y=at^b + c$

Comment: Looking at R-squared and your auto-correlated residuals, it seems to me that you are having here what is called as "spurious regression". These are more discussed in detail under non-stationary or unit root process.

Comment: Is the extra structure scientifically or practically interesting or important? From the high $R^2$ you have it is presumably a smaller part of the structure than the overall shape. That might drive a decision to regard it as notable but not worth including in the model. On the other hand, approximate sinusoids often correspond to some overall intelligible periodicity (e.g. seasonality) which in turn may suggest a modification to your model.